# Can one video asset be rendered on multiple 3d planes all starting at different video.currentTime values in webVR?

Tags: javascript, video, three.js, aframe, webvr

I'm using AFRAME to create a VR video experience. I'm trying to optimize the number of requests for videos because I'm rendering a number of videos displays all around the viewport. Instead of making a unique request for 10 .webm video files I was thinking that doing something like a "video sprite" where all 10 clips are edited into one .webm video file. From here, I'm loading the single video source onto 10 primitive planes in the webVR scene. If I grab the video element, I can change the video scrubbing to anywhere in the video, but this updates every location where the video is playing. Is it possible to grab the WebGL video reference and change the video position on each individual video display?

I suppose it would be great to be able to be able to grab the id of each  element, access the source and update the currentTime value to a unique value for each element... Is this possible in WebGL or is this a limitation of canvas and video assets?

The A-Frame doc url is https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/material.html#video-textures and what I'm trying to do isn't described in the docs but wanted to see if there was anyone who knew how to do this within the community.

A snippet of the app's video code is listed below for context.

Thanks!

```
<a-assets>       
    <video id="testvideo" src="./assets/video/_sm/video_sprite.webmvp8.webm" webkit-playsinline playsinline preload="true"  loop="true"></video>
</a-assets>

....
HTML Code
....
<a-entity layout="type: pyramid; margin: 2; radius: 10;">

<a-video cursor-listener mixin="video" id="video0" material="src: #testvideo" rotation="-1.662 14.897 2.588" position="0.054 1.470 5.472"
opacity="0.0" transparent="true"
animation__opacity="property: opacity; dir: normal; dur: 3000;
                          easing: easeInSine; loop: false; to: 1.0"
></a-video>

<a-video cursor-listener mixin="video" id="video1" material="src: #testvideo" rotation="0 50 0" position="-5 0 -2"
opacity="0.0" transparent="true"
animation__opacity="property: opacity; dir: normal; dur: 3000;
                          easing: easeInSine; loop: false; to: 1.0"
></a-video>

<a-video cursor-listener mixin="video" id="video2" material="src: #testvideo" rotation="0.630 101.643 0.115" position="5.743 0 -1.972"
opacity="0.0" transparent="true"
animation__opacity="property: opacity; dir: normal; dur: 3000;
                          easing: easeInSine; loop: false; to: 1.0"
></a-video>

<a-video cursor-listener mixin="video" id="video4" material="src: #testvideo" rotation="90 90 0" position="0.0 8.165 -1.44"
opacity="0.0" transparent="true" scale="1.2 1.2 1.0"
animation__opacity="property: opacity; dir: normal; dur: 3000;
                          easing: easeInSine; loop: false; to: 1.0"
></a-video>

<a-video cursor-listener mixin="video" id="video5" material="src: #testvideo" position="0 -4 0" rotation="-90 0 0"
opacity="0.0" transparent="true"
animation__opacity="property: opacity; dir: normal; dur: 3000;
                          easing: easeInSine; loop: false; to: 1.0"
></a-video>

<a-video cursor-listener mixin="video" id="video6" material="src: #testvideo" rotation="-27.960 -49.5 3.953" position="-5.186 4.297 2.595"
opacity="0.0" transparent="true"
animation__opacity="property: opacity; dir: normal; dur: 3000;
                          easing: easeInSine; loop: false; to: 1.0"
></a-video>
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip the material component and create your textures manually in three.js. Here's what I'd do:

1. (In HTML or JS), create ten videos pointing to the same `src`. Hopefully, the browser recognizes they're all from the same `src` and does not do duplicate requests.
2. Create 10 different `THREE.VideoTexture`s for each video. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/VideoTexture
3. Now for your planes, you need to specify the UVs to point to a piece of your video. Here is a good tutorial: https://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mappi-1 ... I will release a component later to easily do this for gridded atlases.
4. Then change each plane's video's current time to its respective part of the video.

We'd need to build several components (a simplified `video-material` that creates a basic material with a video texture) and a component to specify UVs (unless you want to do that manually) which I can release later.

So perhaps in the end, an entity you construct may look like `<a-plane geometry="buffer: false" video-material="src: myvideo.mp4; time: 150" uvs="totalColumns: 3; totalRows: 3; row: 2; column: 1"></a-plane>`

`video-material` component may look like:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('video-material', {
  dependencies: ['geometry'],

  schema: {
    src: {type: 'string'},
    time: {type: 'number'}
  },

  init: function () {
    var mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
    this.video = document.createElement('video');
    this.video.setAttribute('src', this.data.src);
    mesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: '#FFF', map: this.video});
    this.video.currentTime = this.data.time;
  }
});
```

Here's my UVs component:

```
var uvs = [new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2()];

/**
 * 1-indexed.
 */
AFRAME.registerComponent('plane-grid-uvs', {
  dependencies: ['geometry'],

  schema: {
    totalColumns: {type: 'int'},
    totalRows: {type: 'int'},
    column: {type: 'int'},
    row: {type: 'int'}
  },

  init: function () {
    var geometry;
    geometry = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry;
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = [new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2()];
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1] = [new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2(), new THREE.Vector2()];
  },

  update: function () {
    var column;
    var columnWidth;
    var data = this.data;
    var geometry;
    var row;
    var rowHeight;

    column = data.column - 1;
    row = data.row - 1;
    columnWidth = 1 / data.totalRows;
    rowHeight = 1 / data.totalColumns;

    uvs[0].set(columnWidth * column,
               rowHeight * row + rowHeight);
    uvs[1].set(columnWidth * column,
               rowHeight * row);
    uvs[2].set(columnWidth * column + columnWidth,
               rowHeight * row);
    uvs[3].set(columnWidth * column + columnWidth,
               rowHeight * row + rowHeight);

    geometry = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry;
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0][0].copy(uvs[0]);
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0][1].copy(uvs[1]);
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0][2].copy(uvs[3]);
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1][0].copy(uvs[1]);
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1][1].copy(uvs[2]);
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][1][2].copy(uvs[3]);
    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a huge help in terms of the process I need to take to create this component! Your code samples were a great jumping off point. I've taken what you've suggested and am working on an A-Frame component that I'll post the result here and in the A-Frame community when complete.

Comment: I've published the component: https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/atlas-uvs for reference.